# Matplotlib: How to make a dotted line consisting of dots (circles)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two smooth dependences y1(x) and y2(x) where x's are distributed irregularly. I want these dependences to be described with dotted lines (`linestyle = ':'`). What i get now in a *.pdf file is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9qPA.png):

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x  = [0, 1, 2,  3,  5,  7, 13, 14]
y1 = [3, 5, 6,  8,  7,  6,  9, 10]
y2 = [1, 7, 8, 10, 14, 18, 20, 23]

ax.plot(x, y1, 
        linestyle = ':',
        linewidth = 4,
        color = 'Green')

ax.plot(x, y2, 
        linestyle = ':',
        linewidth = 4,
        color = 'Blue')

ax.set_ylabel('y(x)')
ax.set_xlabel('x')

plt.savefig("./test_dotted_line.pdf")
```

I played with `dashes = [2,2]` (and other combinations) and `dash_capstyle = 'round'`, but the result looks bad.

Is there a chance to have a dotted line consisting of 'circle' dots?

Comment: Can you show some code which is runnable and gives the same behavior?

Comment: I didn't quite get your point. What do you mean by 'the same behavior'?

Comment: For me the `linestyle=":"` gave a dotted line

Comment: @glanz You currently have provided none of your code. It will be much more helpful if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidG I've changed the post accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can have the actual dotted line itself made up of circles. Is that a crucial part, or would a better looking dotted line be OK?

Comment: @DavidG I also came to the conclusion that it is not possible since dotted line (as I understand) is just a particular case of the dashed line. The possible solution could be using `dashes = [linewidth, linewidth]`. From the other side, this approach can lead to an ambiguous result: the squares "linewidth x linewidth", depending on the slope of the line, look like squares or diamonds.
So now it is now more rhetorical question. Because intuitively (at least for me) I would expect a dotted line be composed of circles...

Answer (score 6):

try this linestyle:

```
ax.plot(x, y1, 
    linestyle = (0,(0.1,2)),
    dash_capstyle = 'round',
    linewidth = 4,
    color = 'Green')
```

output is like this:
[image: output]

Comment: I find that using `linestyle=(0, (0, 2.57))` results in more circular dots (i.e. not elongated) and with a spacing that closely matches that of the default square dots obtained with `':'`,

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick

```
ax.plot(x, y1, linestyle = '--',
    linewidth = 4,
    color = 'Green',
    dashes=(0.5, 5.),
    dash_capstyle='round'
```

)

You have use dashes, set dash_capstyle='round', and then play with the dashes=(ink_points_on, ink_points_off) to get dots of the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `linewidth`. Then it prints little squares - good enough?

You can also round-off the squares with `dash_capstyle = "round"`.

Comment: Sure, I played with it. And couldn't manage to have 'circle' dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lines with dash followed by dot the use **linestyle='-.'**

```
x.plot(x, y2, 
    linestyle = '-.',
    linewidth = 4,
    color = 'Blue')
```

If you want to have your line plot round markers for every data point then use **marker='o'**.

```
x.plot(x, y2, 
    linestyle = '-',
    linewidth = 4,
    marker='o',
    color = 'Blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the markevery property from matplotlib

```
ax.plot(x, y2, 'b.',
        markevery = 4, 
        linewidth = 4)
```

and use it with any marker!